# EmberJS valueBinding without using Helpers

Tags: ember.js

I know that by doing this

```
{{input id="name" valueBinding="name"}}
```

I can get the value of the name input in my controller like so:

```
App.CreateArmyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  name: '',
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      alert(this.get('name'));
    }
  }
});
```

I'd prefer to be able to use standard HTML instead of the input helper.  Is there a way to keep the HTML but still have the binding work?  I also feel like this is a bit smelly to bind the values like this.  If there is a better way to do this using Models, I'd be open to that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no, this is definitely the best/correct way to do it in Ember for input fields.

Considering the binding, you don't have to use valueBinding, you could also do `{{input value=name}}`.